# UITableView Cell to a new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I am trying to go from a `UITableView Cell`, when tapping the Cell, to go to another `ViewController` in swift. I have a `viewController` called MainMenu which is my `UITableView` and I am trying to click on a cell, and go to my other `ViewController`. Can someone please help?

**My code for the UITableView called Main Menu:**

```
class MainMenu: UITableViewController {

    // Set Tabs in Table View Controller
    var tabs = [String]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Name of Tabs
        tabs = ["Scanner","QR-Codes","Cargo","Matrix","Xbox","PS4","Nintendo","Sega","Dreamcast","Xbox360","GameCube","Wii","Challenger","Mustang","Macbook","Logitech"]
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tabs.count
    }
    // Set Tabs in View 
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("scannerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = tabs[indexPath.row]
        print(tabs)
        // return
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just the code to draw the screen. Nowhere are you trying to do anything when a cell is tapped, or moving to another viewController. If you are asking how to make this happen ... there are (literally) hundreds of stackoverflow questions and thousands of tutorials to show how to do this. Please do some research and make an attempt before asking a question.

Comment: Sorry Just needed help @SimonMcLoughlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to implement 2 items:

1 ) create a segue between the TableView and the ViewController you want to go to. Name it something unique.

2) create a prepareForSegue function in your ViewController (i.e., MainMenu). Something like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "UNIQUE NAME FROM PART 1"
    {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? OtherViewController {
            // pass an object here if necessary using destinationVC and dot syntax.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `tableView`'s `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` delegate method, and in it you should present the new view controller.

You can present it modally using the `UIViewController`'s `presentViewController(_:animated:)` method.

Or if you are using storyboards, then create a segue from the prototype cell to the view controller you want to present.

Answer (score 0):

override didSelectRowAtIndexPath, grab the dataSource item at the indexPath and then display your View Controller

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Sudo code but you should get the idea
    let vc: UIViewController = UIViewController()
   // push it 
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
  // or present it
   presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!